# Springboot cacheable key on multiple field method parameters

Tags: spring-boot, caching

I'm trying to cache static lists in spring boot application for static lists based on some conditions. I'm did below

Springboot v2.5.12

```
@Caching(cacheable =
    {
    @Cacheable( value="lists_",  key = "{#a,#b}", condition = "#b=='states'"),
    @Cacheable( value="lists_",  key = "{#a,#b}", condition = "#b=='programs'")    
    })

    public ResponseBody<List<String>> getStaticLists(String a, String b, HttpHeaders headers)
    {
        // implementaionCode
    }
```

Idea is to cache states and programs for each type of a.

But it is not working as expected. Is there anything wrong in above implementation or we need to use custom key generator to generate keys.

Cache different static values based multiple key parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current implementation is that you are defining two contradictory conditions for the same cache. Should be like this:

```
@Cacheable(value="lists_", key="{#a,#b}", condition="#b=='states' or #b=='programs'")
public ResponseBody<List<String>> getStaticLists(String a, String b, HttpHeaders headers)
```